# How do i wrap a string following a search result?

Tags: regex, search, replace, sublimetext3

I've got a javascript file with over 1000 object properties that I want to replace with a function.

Example:

```
myObject.ARANDOMPROPERTY
myObject.THISISAPROPERTY
```

> ...

```
myObject.ANOTHERPROPERTY
```

I want to replace these with functions that wrap the property in a string value. i.e.:

```
myFunction('ARANDOMPROPERTY')
myFunction('THISISAPROPERTY')
```

> ...

```
myFunction('ANOTHERPROPERTY')
```

**The property is always alphabetical and always in all caps. The string can be followed by multiple characters, sometimes a `+`, sometimes a `,` sometimes a linebreak, but never by an alphabetic character.**

I'm currently using SublimeText3 which supports regular expressions, but I'm open to suggestions with other resources.

How do would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, have you tried any regex yet? Looks like a basic regex replacement with a capturing group and a backreference.

Comment: Try `\bmyObject\.([A-Z]+)` and replace with `myFunction('$1')`

Comment: @christopher tool recommendations are _very_ poor fit for Programmers - these would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use  a `\bmyObject\.([A-Z]+)` pattern and replace with `myFunction('$1')`.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary (we only match the next word as a whole word)
- `myObject` - the `myObject` word
- `\.` - a dot
- `([A-Z]+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more uppercase letters.

In the replacement, `$1` references the value inside Group 1.

[image]

V

[image]